# Is my iPad not accurate enough or is it the stylus?

Tags: ipad, resolution, stylus

I made some capacitive styli with my brother, following [this video on Cnet](http://cnettv.cnet.com/make-free-ipad-stylus/9742-1_53-50111166.html?tag=cnetRiver).

I tried using it with the Wacom notebook app, and the handwriting is a teensy bit too large to work as well as a real live "dead tree" notebook.

At the moment, the app feels like a wide ruled notebook, and I'd love to be able to write as much as a college ruled notebook.

Is the problem the tip of the sponge on my styli, or is it the resolution of the iPad?

What can I do to improve the accuracy, so that I can fit more handwritten text on the page?

Comment: Can you use your fingers to make smaller strokes with the wacom app than you can with the stylus? Maybe it is just a limitation of how small it will draw the line in that particular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the iPad screen. No stylus will feel like a real pen. Future versions will likely have more sensitive screens. The best you can do is think of it as a giant index card and a fat marker.

The Wacom software improves the situation a tiny bit by having the zoom mode when writing. You can find other software that allows more zoom, which would make the final product look like a normal page of text, but the act of writing will not be improved.